# Object reference not saved properly in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller i am creating a subcategory object and giving that object a reference to the category it belongs to. Everything works fine when i debug the site but when i load the list of objects from my entityframework db all the category object references are removed. the rest persists. anybody got an idea why this happens ?

Controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "administrator")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CategoryViewModel viewmodel, HttpPostedFileBase Icon)
    {
        SubCategory subcategory = new SubCategory();
        Category category = categorycontroller.getCategoryByName(viewmodel.SelectedValue);

        viewmodel.subcategory.Category = category;
        subcategory = viewmodel.subcategory;
        category.Subcategories.Add(subcategory);

        if (Icon != null && Icon.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Icon.FileName);

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../../Content/icons/"), fileName);
            Icon.SaveAs(path);
            subcategory.Icon = fileName;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            subcategorydb.categories.Attach(category);
            subcategorydb.subcategories.Add(subcategory);
            subcategorydb.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(subcategory);
    }
```

and this is my viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Controllers;

namespace SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models
{
    public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> PossibleValues { get; set; }
        public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
        public SubCategory subcategory { get; set; }

        public CategoryController categorycontroller;

        public CategoryViewModel()
        {
            PossibleValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Category and SubCategory class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategory> Subcategories;

        public Category()
        {
            Subcategories = new List<SubCategory>();
        }
    }

    public class CategoryDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubCategory> subcategories { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Controllers;

namespace SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models
{
    public class SubCategory
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubCategoryDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SubCategory> subcategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i have searched many sites for info on this problem but couldnt find much of help. Anybody here able to identify my problem?

as seen on this screenshot the object is correctly referenced by all means. but when i load the data next time the object reference has disapeared. all other attributes are still there and saved as they should:
[image: Image displaying my debugg of the save process]

thanks AronChan

//// Update ////
I am now getting the following error:

> A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary
>   key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name =
>   SubCategory_Category ]

Comment: Do both of your object relations disappear? You seem to have a 2 way relation: Category <--> Subcategory. And how do your database tables look?

Comment: Yes there is no reference in any of the objects. Im not structuring the tables myself since i use the EntityFramework object oriented database it does all the mapping for me automaticly

Comment: Does `SubCategory` also have a `CategoryId`, and if so what happens if you explicitly set `subCategory.CategoryId = category.CategoryId` as well as `subCategory.Category = category`?

Comment: Allright, a code first approach. I think your db object is the context of your data model. As far as I can remember, you have to put in in a using statement in every method you use it and create a new instance. Maybe the web app keeps connections open and doesnt save changes, but Im just guessing here. The using statement would begin in the Create method, as soon as you start working with entities and would look like this: using(var db = new entitiesContext()){//DB manipalations here, ending with db.SaveChanges();}.

Comment: Adding a categoryid to the subcategory doesnt change anything. shouldnt the object reference be enough as well?

I am using the db.savechanges and when i look at the other methods in some of the autogenerated code that uses the db there is no such thing as using(etc) :S

Answer (score 2):

Your category object won't get saved because it is not attached to the DbContext that you add the subcategory to. The subcategory might know about the reference but the category won't. If there is a lookup table (which there must be if its many to many) I don't see how that record would be saved. Try attaching the category, adding the subcategory and then saving. Personally I have always set up the many-to-many look up tables as their own entity. It is a little easier to visualize what is actually happening as opposed to giving all control to EF.

Also, if you are using code first, make sure your EntityConfigurations are correct. Try running the EdmxWriter over your context to make sure the data model looks exactly how you want it to.

Comment: When i attach the object to my SubCategoryDBContext it gives me the following error:

A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = SubCategory_Category ]

Comment: Does subcategory have a categoryId or parentId property? Make sure you set that to the category.Id. I assume its named parentId or something similar - EF won't be able to find that FK through convention unless you either map it in your Entity Configuration or specifically set it.

Comment: yes the subcategory object has an CategoryID attribute (int). Is it correct to assume that my subcategoryDBContext should contain a DBset of category objects and that i should attach my category object to that context?

Comment: Subcategory DbContext should definitely have a DbSet of category - you are correct.

Comment: You you post your DbContext and your entity configuration as well? might be helpful instead of the view/viewmodel

Comment: Im not sure where to locate the entity configuration so i guess it is pretty much the default settings. atleast i didnt change anything. i also updated the above question to mirror how my code looks now.

Comment: Given the error you have now, it seems that you are trying to save the subcategory that is linked to a category that has not been saved yet. (The foreign key is not finding a legitimate primary key.) Attaching a new category is not the same as .Add. Attach puts the category on the dbset as Unchanged. If it is a new category, this will fail.

Comment: But the category isnt new. It was created beforehand. Though it was created in the other DBset. Perhaps my mistake is not creating a new category in the subcategory dbset then?